# ValidationPipe dont work when use app.useGlobalPipes

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, nestjs

**Hello. I wanna to use ValidationPipe globaly with useGlobalPipes. I use :**

```
import 'dotenv/config';
import {NestFactory} from '@nestjs/core';
import {ValidationPipe} from '@nestjs/common';
import {AppModule} from './app.module';


async function bootstrap() {
    const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
    app.useGlobalPipes(new ValidationPipe({
        transform: true,
        whitelist: true,
    }));
    await app.listen(3000);
}

bootstrap();
```

**But this dont work. Work only when I add VAlidationPipe in my controler :**

```
@Post('register')
@UsePipes(new ValidationPipe({ transform: true, whitelist: true}))
async register(@Body() userDTO: RegisterDTO) {
    const user = await this.userService.create(userDTO);
    const payload: Payload = {
        userName: user.userName,
        seller: user.seller,
    };

    const token = await this.authService.signPayload(payload);
    return {user, token};
}
```

Comment: I can't spot a problem in your code, this should work. Have you tried reinstalling and updating your dependencies with `npm ci` and `npm update`?

Comment: I've got the same problem, any solutions yet ?

Comment: Related ticket: https://github.com/nestjsx/crud/issues/194

Comment: This is not working for me as well. I have the similar experience that you mentioned @Anton Do you have any update for this?

Comment: Still not working in V8, could be?

Answer (score 1):

I came across the same issue, I found the solution was on https://docs.nestjs.com/pipes#global-scoped-pipes:

> Global pipes are used across the whole application, for every controller and every route handler.
>
> Note that in terms of dependency injection, global pipes registered from outside of any module (with useGlobalPipes() as in the example above) cannot inject dependencies since the binding has been done outside the context of any module. In order to solve this issue, you can set up a global pipe directly from any module using the following construction:
>
> ```
>    import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
>    import { APP_PIPE } from '@nestjs/core';
>
>    @Module({
>      providers: [
>        {
>          provide: APP_PIPE,
>          useClass: ValidationPipe,
>        },
>      ],
>    })
>    export class AppModule {}
> ```

Having this in your AppModule makes the global validation pipe work.

Answer (score 0):

Use this construction `(await app).useGlobalPipes(new ValidationPipe)`